# $\Gamma_I(E)$ is an injective $R$-module? $H^i_I(E)=0;\forall i\gt 0$

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

1.Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $M$ an $R$-module, $I$ an ideal in $R$, and $E$ an injective $R$-module.
 Can one claim that $H^i_I(E)=0;\forall i\gt 0$?

2.In the case of noetherian rings we know that [$\Gamma_I(E)$ is an injective $R$-module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882758/gamma-mathfrak-ai-is-an-injective-r-module-for-every-injective-r-mod). 
 Is it also true for *non-noetherian* rings that "$\Gamma_I(E)$ is an injective $R$-module"? (or there is a counter example?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning Question 2: This does not hold if you just omit the noetherian hypothesis. The situation in general is rather complicated. You can take a look at [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/47043/) and some of my other questions or answers there, while waiting for mine and Quy's paper to be published...

Answer (score 1):

$H_I^i$ is a right-derived functor of a left-exact functor. By construction any injective module is acyclic with respect to that functor. So $H_I^i(E)=0$ holds trivially for $E$ injective.

Comment: thank you. any idea for second question?